# minimal maximal ellipsoids

Tags: convex-geometry

Suppose $K$ is a centrally symmetric, strictly convex body in $\mathbb{R}^2$. Let denote the curvature and the support function of $\partial K$, boundary of $K$, respectively with $\kappa$ and $s$. If $m\le\frac{\kappa}{s^3}(K)\le M$ for some positive numbers $m$ and $M$, does it mean there are ellipsoids $E_1$ and $E_2$ such that $E_1\subseteq K\subseteq E_2$ and $$\frac{\kappa}{s^3}({E_1})=M,~~~ \frac{\kappa}{s^3}(E_2)=m ~~~~? $$

Comment: Could you say more about what $s$ is?  I think of a "support function of $X$" as being a function that is 1 for points in $X$ and 0 otherwise.  But apparently not in this case.

Comment: @Carl Feynman 
The support function  $h_A:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ 
of a  non-empty closed convex set $A$ in $\mathbb{R}^n$ is given by 
:$ h_A(x)=\sup\{ x\cdot a: a\in A\},$

Comment: I think it should be $M$ for the smaller ellipsoid and $m$ for the larger one.

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov edited.

Comment: It seems that $\kappa/s^3$ is not constant for an ellipsoid. Shouldn't it be $\kappa/s^4$? Also, could you provide some motivation or background about this affine curvature or however it is called? For example, if it is constant, does this imply that the surface is an ellipsoid? 

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov I believe if $E\subseteq\mathbb{R}^n$ is an ellipsoid centered at the origin then  $\mathcal{K}/s^{n+1}$ is constant, where $\mathcal{K}$ is the Gauss curvature of $\partial K$ the boundary of $K$.

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov $\mathcal{K}/s^{n+1}$ is called centro-affine curvature.

Comment: Sorry, I was confused by the word "ellipsoid" (rather than "ellipse") and thought that it was in $\mathbb R^3$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes this is true. Let me handle the inner ellipse, the outer one is similar.

For brevity, denote $\kappa/s^3$ by $a$. It is easy to see that
$$
 a = \frac{\dot\gamma\wedge\ddot\gamma}{(\gamma\wedge\dot\gamma)^3}
$$
where $t\mapsto \gamma(t)$ is any counter-clockwise parametrization of the boundary curve. For an ellipse, this is a constant inverse proportional to the square of the area. So we have to prove that the maximum-area ellipse contained in $K$ has $a\le M$.

So let $E$ be the maximum-area ellipse contained in $K$. Since the problem is centro-affine invariant, we may assume that $E$ is the unit circle. Then we have to prove that $M\ge 1$.

Consider the points where $\partial K$ touches $\partial E$. One easily sees that the intervals between these points on the circle are no greater than $\pi/2$, otherwise $E$ could be made larger. Choose coordinates so that one of the touch points is $(1,0)$, then there is another touch point of the form $(\cos\theta,\sin\theta)$ where $0<\theta\le\pi/2$. Observe that the arc of $\partial K$ between these touch points is contained in the square $[0,1]^2$.

Parametrize $\partial K$ by spanned area, i.e. by a curve $t\mapsto\gamma(t)$ such that $\gamma\wedge\dot\gamma=1$. Then $\gamma\wedge\ddot\gamma=0$, hence $\ddot\gamma(t)=-a(t)\gamma(t)$ for all $t$ where $a(t)$ is the centro-affine curvature. Let $\gamma(t)=(x(t),y(t))$, then $\ddot x(t)=-a(t)x(t)$ and $\ddot y(t)=-a(t)y(t)$. Suppose that $M=\sup a(t)<1$. Since $x(0)=1$, $\dot x(0)=0$, $y(0)=0$ and $\dot y(0)=1$, a standard comparison theorem for equations of the form $\ddot x=-ax$ implies that $x(t)>\cos t$ and $y(t)>\sin t$ for all $t\in(0,\pi/2]$. Therefore $x(t)^2+y(t)^2>1$ for all $t\in(0,\pi/2]$ and $y(\pi/2)>1$. This means that $\gamma$ leaves the square $[0,1]^2$ before is has a chance to touch the circle again, a contradiction.

Comment: @Sergei Ivanov Superbe!